# KnockoutJS: How to Access Index of Grandparent in a Nested Observable Array?

Tags: knockout.js

I need to access the "grandparent" index of my nested observable array in my for each.

Here's the structure of my HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Stores">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="add-section">
                            <div data-bind="click: $root.OpenCountryDialog.bind($data, $index())"><img></div>
                            <span>Add Country</span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- ko foreach: Countries-->
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div data-bind=" text: Name"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <div alt="add"  data-bind="click: $root.OpenStateDialog.bind($data, $index(),$parentContext.$index())"><img></div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- ko foreach: ShipToStates -->
                                <div>
                                    <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="icon-add" alt="add" **"ACCESS IT HERE"**><img></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <!-- MORE CONTENTS HERE-->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

So far, I can access the index under Stores using $index, then under Countries by $parentContext.$index(). How about the child of States foreach? How can I access the "index" of the Stores inside it?

Please see **"ACCESS IT HERE"** in the code for reference.

My observable array looks like this:

```
Stores : {
           Name:
           Countries : {
                        Name:
                        States : {
                                  Name:
                        }
         }
```

}

Comment: You could add an alias to your foreach:  https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html (see 'Note 3: Using “as” to give an alias to “foreach” items').  Because you are using containerless control flow syntax, this link 'https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1002' shows you how to add alias.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using $parentContext.$parentContext.$index()